# IntelliJ Structural Search in PhpStorm to find 2 default statements within Switch block

Tags: php, intellij-idea, phpstorm, php-7, structural-search

I need to find all `switch` blocks which has 2 `default` cases:

```
switch (1) {
    default:
        echo "Default 1";
        break;
    default:
        echo "Default 2";
        break;
}
```

Trying this:

```
switch () {
$s$
default:
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to be achievable with the structural search. Any reason you are not happy with built-in Language Level inspection? https://prnt.sc/tgvrlk

Comment: @EugeneMorozov I am migrating project from PHP 5.6 to PHP 7.4, i need to find this kind of switch blocks throughout the project, there are like 10K+ switch cases in project and it will be very tedious to check one by one

Comment: Language Level inspection is not let you find in entire folder

Comment: How come? https://recordit.co/aVch7JrFat